# In visual studio, as I am stepping through code, is there a way to execute a method call without stepping into it?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Let's say I have

```
int a()
{
/* Tons of code
....*/
return someInt;
}

void main()
{
/* Tons of code
....*/

int k = a();

/* Tons of code
....*/
}
```

Next, lets pretend that I'm debugging one step at a time and about to go into the

```
int k = a();
```

statement but that I just want it executed without stepping through a() manually.
Is there something I can do instead of F11 so it executes until the next statement in the method.

Right now I set a breakpoint after the call to a(), but I'm thinking there may be a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it as simple as Step Over?

Comment: I thought step over wouldn't execute the line, just step over it. I want the call to a() to be executed, just not step into it-- I guess I should just try it.

Comment: Step Over does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, use F10, "step over."

Answer (score 3):

StepOver is definitely what you want but I have a tip for you:

If you never want to step into a method (or class / struct etc) you can apply the DebuggerStepThroughAttribute to it and the debugger will ***always*** step over it unless you've explicitly put a breakpoint inside.

For properties, you have put put the attribute on the get / set accessors.

In your example:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
int a()
{
/* Tons of code
....*/
return someInt;
}

void main()
{
/* Tons of code
....*/

int k = a();

/* Tons of code
....*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, press F10 to step over the statement.

Answer (score 2):

F10 to step over, or, if you have already stepped into a method, you can use Shift+F11 to step out of it.